# data.table with Caret (Classification And REgression Training) package

Tags: r, data.table, r-caret

I try to reproduce the examples from the following site:[Create predictive models in R with Caret][1]; making use of the data.table package.
This is the script:

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
mtcarsDT<-data.table(mtcars)
print(mtcarsDT,topn=3)
# Simple linear regression model (lm means linear model)
model <-mtcarsDT[, train(mpg ~ wt,
                         data =.SD,
                         method = "lm"),]

# Multiple linear regression model
model <- ,train(mpg ~ .,
               data = mtcarsDT,
               method = "lm")

# Ridge regression model
model <-train(mpg ~ .,
               data = mtcarsDT,
               method = "ridge")
```

But when trying to implement Multiple linear regression model and Ridge regression model with the syntax used when writing Simple linear regression model,
I receive the following alert:

```
# Multiple linear regression model
model <- mtcarsDT[,train(mpg ~ .,
              data = .SD,
              method = "lm"),]
**Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument**
# Ridge regression model
model <- mtcarsDT[,train(mpg ~ .,
                data = .SD,
                method = "ridge"),]
**Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument**
```

How to proceed?
What am I doing wrong?
[1]: https://towardsdatascience.com/create-predictive-models-in-r-with-caret-12baf9941236

Comment: What is your expected output? Because if I use `mtcarsDT[, train(mpg ~ wt, data =.SD, method = "ridge"),]` I get a model outcome back. (same for "lm", "glm", etc, etc).

Comment: I closed RStudio and opened it again by running the script again and everything
solved.
I am not used to restarting RStudio every time I run a Script !!!
What command to use so that I reset everything; Environment, Device Plot and Console?